# "Deny from all" but still allow WordPress to access files?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've searched this site without finding the answer to my specific query. Many apologies if I have overlooked the answer.

I'm looking to block direct access to the files in a folder - which I have learned I can do with "deny from all" in .htaccess - AND allow WordPress access to these files. The idea is not to let anyone access the images directly, but still have them show up in blog posts. When I use "deny from all", WordPress does not have access. How do I fix that?

Comment: Wordpress does not “access” the images – the client’s browser does. And if you forbid that – then obviously, he can’t. What you are locking for is called “hot link protection”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "allow WordPress access to these files", I'm guessing what you really mean is "allow people who are on a WordPress page to have direct access to these files", because it's not wordpress that is accessing the files, it's still the client/browser accessing them directly. That's why when you use `Deny from all`, they can't see images linked in a word press page.

You can deny by referer, though there's easily ways to get around that. Something like this in the htaccess file in your document root for example (preferably before any wordpress rules):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://your.wordpress-site.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [NC,L,F]
```

would deny access to images if the images aren't linked from your wordpress site (replace `your.wordpress-site.com` with the hostname of your site).

Comment: Thank you so much for recognizing what I really meant and answering that question, Jon! Your solution serves the purpose. I feel sheepish and very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: @EvaG. no problem, just keep in mind that blocking by referer isn't a guaranteed way to prevent access.

Comment: Thank you. 100% protection isn't necessary; I think if someone really wants to copy my content they can already do that by becoming a member and taking screenshots. I just would like to make it a little bit difficult for people to share the content by sharing a link with non-members. This way the content won't be viewable by non-members unless someone really puts forth effort to make it happen. Thanks again! :)